# How to debug Windows PC suddenly not sending Ethernet packets?

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet

I've been debugging a problem on a HP compact PC (https://www.cdw.com/product/hp-workstation-z2-g9-wolf-pro-security-sff-core-i5-12500-3-ghz-16-g/7517831) where the PC will suddenly stop sending any Ethernet packets for a second or two, in some cases even 3. Then it will suddenly resume as if nothing happened. Interestingly, it will send responses to packets that came in while the PC wasn't sending anything so it appears to still be receiving packets.

The Ethernet connection is static IP (192.168.x.x) on its own switch with a few other industrial devices (IO controllers, RFID readers and a monitoring PC running Wireshark)

Things I've tried:

1. Disable power savings in control panel and device manager
2. Switch off all protocols except TCP v4
3. Three different Ethernet adapters, including a USB bridge
4. Two different switches
5. Different Ethernet cables
6. Windows 10 22H2 and most current Windows 11

At this point it feels like something about this specific PC model as the monitoring PC can ping all the other devices on the network continuously without hiccups.

Which tools should I use next? I've looked through the Windows event log but cannot find anything that indicates a problem so I'm hoping to get some suggestions what kind of in-kernel tracing tools or similar could pinpoint what's causing this.

Comment: This is my generic answer to 90% of the questions that come in here at SU.  Use the process monitor.  Figure out how to filter down what the problem is.  The filters are a pain to figure out but will the tool will provide you with 100% of the information you desire as long as the problem isn't in Kernel space.

Comment: That's a good idea - I've used procmon to track file and registry accesses but it can do more. Since I can pinpoint the event in time down to fractions of a second I should be able to find the needle in the haystack.